# msg error catkin_make

Tags: ros, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i try to make custom messages in my workspace. i follow the tutorial, but when i'm catkin_make workspace, i get erorr like this and i try to catkin_make install and get same error. what should i do?? thank you

> ---
>
> mfikih15@lenovo:~/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut$

> catkin_make Base path:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut

> Source space:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/src

> Build space:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/build

> Devel space:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel

> Install space:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/install

> 

> ##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in

> "/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut

> /build"

> 

> -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel

> -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel;/home/mfikih15
> /Documents/joystick/devel;/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/robotTenggelam/devel;/home/mfikih15/Documents
> /pkm/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic

> -- This workspace overlays: /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel;/home/mfikih15/Documents/joystick/devel;/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/robotTenggelam/devel;/home/mfikih15/Documents/pkm/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic

> -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/python

> -- Using Debian Python package layout

> -- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy

> -- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON

> -- Call enable_testing()

> -- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/build/test_results

> -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built

> -- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7

> -- catkin 0.7.6

> -- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on

> -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> -- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:

> -- ~~  - groundserver

> -- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> -- +++ processing catkin package: 'groundserver'

> -- ==> add_subdirectory(groundserver)

> -- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy

> -- groundserver: 1 messages, 0 services

> -- Configuring done

> -- Generating done

> -- Build files have been written to: /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/build

> 

> ##### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in

> "/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/build"

> ##### [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp

> Scanning dependencies of target

> killManual [  0%] Built target

> std_msgs_generate_messages_py Scanning

> dependencies of target remoteServer [

> 9%] Building CXX object

> groundserver/CMakeFiles/killManual.dir/src/killManual.cpp.o

> [  9%] Built target

> std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp [ 18%]

> Building CXX object

> groundserver/CMakeFiles/remoteServer.dir/src/remoteServer.cpp.o

> [ 18%] Built target

> _groundserver_generate_messages_check_deps_inputRemote

> [ 18%] Built target

> std_msgs_generate_messages_eus [ 18%]

> Built target

> std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs [

> 27%] Built target

> groundserver_generate_messages_lisp [

> 45%] Built target

> groundserver_generate_messages_py [

> 54%] Generating C++ code from

> groundserver/inputRemote.msg [ 72%]

> Built target

> groundserver_generate_messages_eus

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File

> "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py",

> line 41, in

> ```
> import genmsg.template_tools   File
> ```

> "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py",

> line 39, in

> ```
> import em ImportError: No module named em [ 81%] Built target
> ```

> groundserver_generate_messages_nodejs

> groundserver/CMakeFiles/groundserver_generate_messages_cpp.dir/build.make:62:

> recipe for target

> '/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel/include/groundserver/inputRemote.h'

> failed make[2]: ***

> [/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel/include/groundserver/inputRemote.h]

> Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:690:

> recipe for target

> 'groundserver/CMakeFiles/groundserver_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all'

> failed make[1]: ***

> [groundserver/CMakeFiles/groundserver_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all]

> Error 2 make[1]: *** Waiting for

> unfinished jobs.... [ 90%] Linking CXX

> executable

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel/lib/groundserver/killManual

> [100%] Linking CXX executable

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel/lib/groundserver/remoteServer

> [100%] Built target killManual [100%]

> Built target remoteServer

> Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all'

> failed make: *** [all] Error 2

> Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

> mfikih15@lenovo:~/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut$

> catkin_make install Base path:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut

> Source space:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/src

> Build space:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/build

> Devel space:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel

> Install space:

> /home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/install

> 

> ##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in

> "/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/build"

> 

> 

> ##### Running command: "make install -j4 -l4" in "/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/build"

> ##### [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp [ 36%]

> Built target remoteServer [ 36%] Built

> target killManual [ 36%] Built target

> std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp [ 36%]

> Built target

> std_msgs_generate_messages_py [ 36%]

> Built target

> std_msgs_generate_messages_eus [ 36%]

> Built target

> _groundserver_generate_messages_check_deps_inputRemote

> [ 36%] Built target

> std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs [

> 54%] Built target

> groundserver_generate_messages_py [

> 63%] Generating C++ code from

> groundserver/inputRemote.msg [ 72%]

> Built target

> groundserver_generate_messages_lisp [

> 90%] Built target

> groundserver_generate_messages_eus

> [100%] Built target

> groundserver_generate_messages_nodejs

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File

> "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py",

> line 41, in

> ```
> import genmsg.template_tools   File
> ```

> "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py",

> line 39, in

> ```
> import em ImportError: No module named em
> ```

> groundserver/CMakeFiles/groundserver_generate_messages_cpp.dir/build.make:62:

> recipe for target

> '/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel/include/groundserver/inputRemote.h'

> failed make[2]: ***

> [/home/mfikih15/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut/devel/include/groundserver/inputRemote.h]
> Error 1 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:690:

> recipe for target

> 'groundserver/CMakeFiles/groundserver_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all'

> failed make[1]: ***

> [groundserver/CMakeFiles/groundserver_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all]

> Error 2 Makefile:138: recipe for

> target 'all' failed make: *** [all]

> Error 2 Invoking "make install -j4

> -l4" failed mfikih15@lenovo:~/Documents/kapalTenggelam/serverGabut$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278992/msg-error-catkin_make/) by [lp02781](https://answers.ros.org/users/33096/lp02781/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm thinking you're running into an issue with the `em` and `empy` modules.

See #q257331.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lp02781](https://answers.ros.org/users/33096/lp02781/) on 2018-01-06**:
it work, thank you